# Is there a default sort order for cursors in COBOL reading from DB2?

Tags: sql, cursor, db2, cobol

I am trying to understand how the following COBOL cursor works:

```
T43624     EXEC SQL
T43624         DECLARE X_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
T43624             SELECT
T43624                    A
T43624                   ,B
T43624                   ,C
T43624                   ,D
T43624                   ,E
T43624                   ,F
T43624             FROM
T43624                    X
T43624             WHERE
T43624                    L        = :PP-L
T43624               AND  M <= :PP-M
T43624               AND  N  = :PP-N
T43624               AND  O        = :PP-O
T43624               AND  P       = :PP-P
T43624               AND  Q        = :PP-Q
T43624     END-EXEC.
```

Given that there is no ORDER BY clause, in what order will the rows be returned? Could a default have been set somewhere?

Comment: . . I doubt it.  Tables are inherently unordered.  DB2 (to the best of my knowledge) doesn't offer a way to express a default sort order, and I doubt that COBOL would override this.  It is possible, in some databases, that if `X` is a view with an `order by`, then the rows would be returned in that order (possible, but not required by the standard).

Comment: Note: clustering index's are often used with Mainframe DB2 DB's, while this does not guarantee an order an order, most rows will be stored in this sequence.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, the order the rows are returned in is unpredictable and non-repeatable. Either the order is not relevant to the COBOL program in question, or the program does not work. If you are looking for a bug, you may have found it. If the program does not require the data to be in any particular sequence, then there is no problem with the code.

Comment: What platform? DB2 generally follows SQL standards and has no guaranteed order if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause. Also, different platforms may provide features such as clustered indexes that aren't needed or do not apply on other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default sort order for results returned from a DB/2 select statement. If you need, or expect, data to be
returned in some order then the ordering must be specified using an ORDER BY clause on the SQL predicate.

You may find that results appear to be ordered but that ordering is just an artifact of the access paths used
by DB/2 to resolve the perdicate. Simple queries requiring only stage 1 processing are often resolved using an index 
and these are typically ordered
because the undelying index follows that order. This is totally unreliable and may change due to a
rebind causing a different access path to be used or when the underlying index is in need of being rebuilt (after
many insertions/deletions, lack of free space etc).

Queries that require stage 2 processing tend to come out ordred, but this too is just an artifact of query resolution
and should never be relied upon.

COBOL does not excercise any inherent control over DB/2 operations other that what may be achieved using SQL alone.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely "default" order is by the [clustering index](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_clusteringindexes.htm):

> A *clustering index* determines how rows are physically ordered
>   (clustered) in a table space.

However, it does not *guarantee* the ordering (emphasis mine):

> When a table has a clustering index, an INSERT statement causes DB2 to
>   insert the records ***as nearly as possible*** in the order of their index
>   values.

Using the [REORG utility](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.ugref/src/tpc/db2z_utl_reorgtablespace.htm), you can have DB2 reorder a table by the clustering index.

Having said that, if you need an order, then don't push your luck and depend on the (undependable) clustering order. As @Gordon Linoff said, the SQL does not require a default sorting order, and DB2 does not enforce one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **default** ordering. The order the records are returned to the program will be determined by the access method DB2 uses.

For example on a single Table query if DB2 does a

```
Full Table Scan   Rows most likely in table sequence (small tables)
Index Scan        Rows most likely in Index sequence (small tables)

Other             Possibly table sequence, but could be index
                  sequence or a random sequence.
```

To confuse things further

- On mainframe DB2, Clustering Index's are often used (store DB in Index sequence).
- DB2 can change its **access method** each time there is a **bind**.
- For huge tables, I suspect it might use multiple readers, which would change the above order's.

  If you need/want the data in a specific sequence, use the **Order by** clause